# Why switch false always return first case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to understand `switch` behaviour when it deals with `false`.

```
let grade = 65;

switch(false){
  case grade >= 90:
    console.log(grade);
    console.log("You did great!");
    break;
  case grade >= 80:
    console.log("You did good!");
    break;
  default:
    console.log(grade, "is not a letter grade!");
```

I don't understand why grade will always hit first case in the code above

I was expecting none of the case being fulfilled because of `switch(false)`, and there should be no console log printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`swtich` compares the expression in the `case` with the value passed to `switch`.

`(grade >= 90) === false`

---

I strongly recommend only using simple values in `case`s and using `if` / `else` for more complex logic like you have here. Putting expressions in `case`s is unintuative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against the opposite of the expression, because of the double negation.

```
switch (false) {
    case !(grade >= 90): // code
}
```

vs

```
switch (true) {
    case grade >= 90: // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> The `switch` statement evaluates an expression, matching the
> expression's value against a series of `case` clauses, and executes
> statements after the first `case` clause with a matching value, until a
> `break` statement is encountered. The `default` clause of a `switch`
> statement will be jumped to if no `case` matches the expression's value.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score -1):

It's because, it compares passed value (`false`) with case equation (which is also `false` in first case), so `false === false` is `true` (Yes it's `===`, not `==`), so it's going into the first case.